# Linq Select projections with calculated values

Tags: c#, linq, projection

What I've noticed when using Select with an anonymous function or other value that's calculated at runtime is that every time you access the output IEnumerable object is that the projection recalculates the value. Example:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Addr { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public A Whatever {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

Random rand = new Random();
IEnumerable<B> listOfBs = someListOfA.Select( x => new B()
{
    Id = rand.Next(),
    Whatever = x
});
```

What I've noticed is that every time I parse through the list listOfB and use the Id property, the Id is reevaluated with another `rand.Next()`.

```
foreach( B b in listOfBs )
{
  doSomething( b.Id );
}
```

I haven't seen what would cause this in the documentation on C# projections. Its almost as if Select generates an anonymous function that is reevaluated every time its accessed. So, two questions:

1. what is this behavior I'm seeing.
2. how can I avoid this, but still be able to convert a list of one type to another list of another type.

Let me know if my bad example code conveys my point.

Comment: Did you try running this sample code? Does it have different random value every time you iterate thru `listOfBs`?

Comment: `var someListOfA = new List<A>() { new A() }; ... foreach (var b in listOfBs) { Console.WriteLine(b.Id); } foreach (var b in listOfBs) { Console.WriteLine(b.Id); }` console: "756542965 1936550407", this demonstrates the issue OP is seeing.

Comment: This is as expected before you execute query, linq has difered execution. If you do listOfB = listOfB.ToList() query will be executed...

Comment: Yes, that's what I've seen as well, calling ToList() solves the "problem".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's expected and that's because most LINQ methods are lazy - that means they don't enumerate the source until results are needed. In you particular scenario `listOfBs` is not really a materialized collection of `B` objects. Instead, it's a definition on **how** to translate `someListOfA` into a collection of `B` objects. `Select` returns an object which implements `IEnumerable<T>` and stores both reference to the source collection and the projection delegate. The projection is done when results are needed, e.g. when you iterate over the collection in `foreach`. If you iterate multiple times the projection will be performed multiple times. Which is exactly what you're seeing.

Call `ToList` or `ToArray` to materialize the results immediately:

```
IEnumerable<B> listOfBs = someListOfA.Select( x => new B()
{
    Id = rand.Next(),
    Whatever = x
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Also dangerous if you're not expecting it. Linq allows you to easily write broken code if you're not careful, much the asynchronous programming models that may or may not use the same thread after awaiting. The syntactical sugar can catch the unwary.

Comment: I guess another question is how inefficient it is to call ToList() after already parsing the whole IEnumerable list of elements. Does it run through the list multiple times?

Comment: `source.Select().ToList` will only enumerate the source collection once.